# Search server-side CSV with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I have a server-side CSV that I would like to see if possible I can get a JavaScript (or even jquery) to search using an input box and view results.

The CSV has a postcode and suburb 'headings' I'm wanting to search the first heading (postcode) and the result list any suburb within that postcode.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother outputting a CSV from the server-side. unless the data structure involved is a one-dimensional array.

You're better to output Json into a HTML Dom element (Using a json serializer on the sever-side), then pick it up with jQuery, e.g $('#myElement'); Then JSON.parse(str); into a javascript object and do your searching then.